# Can I reshape that code using foreach and initial declaration

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

I have to set a property which expects to get an array hence I need an array of instances of class X, as follow:

```
X[] x = new X[]
{
  new X () { Parameter = parameter },
  new X () { Parameter = parameter2 }
  // ...
}
```

Since the parameter are generated while runtime and stored in a list, the instances should be created dynamically. I get my intended aim with that code

```
X[] x = new X[list.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
  x[i] = new X() { Parameter = list.ElementAt(i) }
}
```

These lines do their job, however, I'm not satisfied with these lines. I'd like to change some things, i.e. code which looks like that Pseudo-Code

```
X[] x = new X[]
{
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    new X () { Parameter = item }
  }
}
```

This code, however, will not work. Is there a way to implement such a code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
X[] x = list.Select(param => new X { Parameter = param }).ToArray();
```

Here, `.Select(...)` creates a projection, i.e. a sequence that for every item in the list performs the `new X {...}` operation; the `.ToArray()` converts that sequence to an array.

Comment: Could consider using `var` too.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart true; I left that so it would be clear to the OP that we do indeed end up with an `X[]`. But indeed, `var x = ...` would work identically. Same number of characters, of course ;p

Comment: @MarcGravell It's only the same number of characters if the type name is actually `X`, which I sure hope it's not (unless perhaps it's generic, which seems unlikely).